# Unable to populate Typescript Tuple of [string, string] from data source

Tags: angular, typescript

I am attempting to read an `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>` into a Typescript array that will populate a combo box. From there I want to get the first string of the selected item.

However every attempt I try in my Typescript code ends up converting the tuple from the data access layer into an array of single strings.

I have also discovered that most of the examples I have found for defining the tuple do not compile for me. For example type SomeTuple = (string | string)[]; does not work at all.

Currently I have batches defined as: 
`batches = [String];` I've also tried `batches = [String, String];` and `batches = [];` Normally using [] works great for me.

The call to the data service looks like this:

```
  getOpenBatches() {
    this.itemSvc.getOpenBatches(this.blah).subscribe(data => (this.batches = data));
  }
```

batches ends up looking like this:  [One string for each item] [It also has unwanted paranthesis]
“(Widget 1, Locked By Bill)”
“(Widget 2, Locked By Tom)”
“(Widget 3, Locked By Harry)”

I was expecting something like this:  [Two strings for each item]
“Widget 1”, “Locked By Bill”
“Widget 2”, “Locked By Tom”
“Widget 3”, “Locked By Harry”

This is a piece of the data access layer.

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> tup = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
foreach (var res in result)
{
    Tuple<string, string> t = new Tuple<string, string>(res.bn, res.bu);
    tup.Add(t);
}

return tup;   // tup is a IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>
```

The debugger shows me that each row in the array has two items of type string, which is exactly what I am expecting.

Example: Item1 = “Widget 1”, Item2 = “Locked By Bill”

My goal is to have these pairs of items be loaded into the batches array of string|string Tuples, and not the single string that I am seeing now.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had not modified the controller in the DataAccess layer. I was still returning a List after all.

```
 public IActionResult GetOpenBatches()
 {
     var openBatches = _adminRepository.GetOpenBatches();
     return Ok(openBatches);
     //return Ok(Mapper.Map<List<string>>(openBatches))
 }
```

I commented out the incorrect line, and it is working now.